# Calling an overload with null: casting vs default

Tags: c#, casting, overloading, default, explicit

Not sure if this is a bit of a superfluous question, but consider I have these methods:

```
void Foo(SomeClass x)
{
    //Some code
}

void Foo(AnotherClass x)
{
    //Some code
}
```

And let's say that I want to call a specific overload (the SomeClass one) with null, here are my options:

```
Foo((SomeClass)null)

Foo(null as SomeClass)

Foo(default(SomeClass))
```

Basically, which is the best to go for? Are there any significant performance differences between the different approaches? Is a specific way generally considered more 'elegant' than the others?

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't make a semantic difference (I wonder what IL differences there are, if any, though..). Be consistent. I always use the former as I like the "type up front" in C#.

Comment: I think you might want to reevaluate what you're trying to do here.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option 4: create another overload:

```
void Foo()
```

Calling with an explicit null that you need to cast? Umm...eww...

To "officially" answer your question. Try it!

```
var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    Foo(null as string);
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    Foo((string)null);
}           
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    Foo(default(string));
}
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I got ~4ms for all 3 approaches.

When I open up the program in reflector, I see that all of the calls have been turned into:         `Foo((string) null);`

So, you can choose whatever you find most readable. The IL all ends up exactly the same.

Comment: Unfortunately in my case, the overload Foo() already exists, which calls Foo(SomeClass x) with another "default" non-null value. Strange approach, I know, but it's part of the old code I'm working with here :P Thanks for the performance breakdown, looks like I'll go with the explicit cast for consistency, as it's used elsewhere already :)